# Bumb Up Hover effec, destroys the line under the elemnt

Tags: html, css

i whant the bump hover effect, so that if someone goes with the mouse over an card it lifts up. the problem is that if someone goes over the last element it will destroy the line under it. its always by the last object per each line, and im stucked here.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 text-center" >

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model44.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Alex Libby</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model43.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Aida Artiles</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model45.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Alex Zambiazi</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model42.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Adeola Zimmer</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model8.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Aki von Glasgow</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="model-card">
            <div class="model-card-image">
                <img src="img/models/model1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-content">
                <p>Anja Peric</p>
            </div>
            <div class="model-card-action">
                <a href="#">Pups</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i have here the html and css file in a bootply file. [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HZPg1VB31K)

```
.model-card {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 0em 0.7em 1.4em 0.7em;
background-color: #fff;
transition: box-shadow .25s;
width: 15em;
padding:0px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
float: left; margin: 15px; -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out; -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out; -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
```

}

```
.model-card:hover {
margin-top: 2px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` and `translate` instead of `margin` for the animation, and update the `transition` property.

So replace

```
.model-card:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

with

```
.model-card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/jHToqy4fwh**